# ¿Cómo hacer que al presionar una tecla especifica se ponga el el reproductor Windows Media Player en pantalla completa?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer un reproductor, usando el reproductor Windows Media Player que viene como componente en Visual Studio. Quiero que al presionar la tecla 'F' o la tecla 'F11' el reproductor se ponga en pantalla completa. El problema es que al apretar la F o el F11 no pasa nada. No se cual pueda ser el problema, les dejo el método:

```
private void form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F || e.KeyData == Keys.F11)
        {
            wmv.fullScreen = true; //wmv es el reproductor
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final, cambié el método por un PreviewKeyDown y ahora funciona bien.